# Simplest nodejs app on cloud9 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud9

I tried to launch a simplest app, described here: https://community.c9.io/t/writing-a-node-js-app/1731
The single file (server-cloud9.js) I try to launch contains the following code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

The command saved in the config is, accordingly:

```
node server-cloud9.js
```

But after calling the Run command I got following message:

```
Your code is running at https://js-world-srgg6701.c9users.io.
Important: use process.env.PORT as the port and process.env.IP as the host in your scripts!

module.js:327
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/workspace/node'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3

Process exited with code: 1
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run it from the User Interface, by clicking the green play button:

1. Select your file, in your case it's `server-cloud9.js`
2. Click the green play button in the upper side of the UI.

And magic is done.